# My code is failing the time limit even though it seems to produce the correct output. How do I decrease the time taken for my code to work?

Tags: c++, algorithm, for-loop, if-statement, time-complexity

Question - For a positive integer n let's define a function f:
f(n) =  - 1 + 2 - 3 + .. + ( - 1)^n*n
Your task is to calculate f(n) for a given integer n.

Input -
The single line contains the positive integer n (1 ≤ n ≤ 10^15).

Output -
Print f(n) in a single line.

Link to question - https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/486/A

My code -

```
int main(){
    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);

    long long t,sum=0;
    cin >> t;
    for(long long i=1;i<=t;i++){
        if(i%2!=0){
            sum = sum - i;
        }else{
            sum = sum + i;
        }
    }
    cout << sum;
}
```

The code seems to produce the correct output, however the time limit is a problem. Time limit per test is 1 second. When the input is 1000000000000000 , it says time limit exceeded and fails the test case. How do I reduce the time taken for my code?

Comment: You should consider examining the problem carefully. Can you find a way to do this in constant time rather than n? It might help you to write down the first 5 or so values of n and the corresponding values of f(n)

Comment: You should be aware that such "competitions" are almost always about tricks, and have limited real-world applicability.

Comment: Here's a way to calculate for n=6: `(-1 + 2) + (-3 + 4) + (-5 + 6) = 1 + 1 + 1 = 3`. You can generalize this trick.

Comment: Check the inputs: 10^15 nanoseconds is almost twelve days (and you probably won't do one iteration in a singe nanosecond).

Comment: You can often tell the expected complexity by looking at the input range, and this is one of the first things you should think about when you are solving an algo puzzle. You can often rule out certain complexities by using simple calculcations. 10^15 is only going to be possible in a reasonable timeframe if the algorithm is O(1) or O(log n). If the limit is 10^3, then probably an O(n^2) solution (or worse) is expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your algorithm has `O(N)` complexity, hence it fails.  We can come up with an O(1) solution here.
Look at values of `f(n)`, to make it easier.

1. `f(1) = -1`
2. `f(2) = 1`
3. `f(3) = -2`
4. `f(4) = 2`
5. `f(5) = -3`
6. `f(6) = 3`

2 simple observations here:

1. `f(n)` is positive if `n%2==0`
2. `abs(f(n)) = ceil(n/2)`

Using these facts, the algorithm gets reduced to `O(1)` complexity.

Comment: Thanks I got it, finding the pattern helps a lot.

Answer (score 2):

```
int main()
{
    long long t,sum=0;
    cin >> t;
    if(t%2)
        sum-=((t+1)/2);
    else
        sum+=(t/2);
 
    cout << sum;
}
```

For a given odd 'n' sum is -(n+1)/2
For a given even 'n' sum is (n+1)/2

You can find the pattern by writing down few examples. I tested this and also accepted in codeforces. Time complexity is O(1).